# Using Qt Libraries with ROS Indigo CMake Error

Tags: ros-indigo, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to incorporate an existing Qt GUI into a ROS node. I'm initially just trying to get the CMakeLists.txt to build successfully in QtCreator 2.7.2. I keep getting an error that:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt4" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt4Config.cmake
    qt4-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt4" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt4_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt4" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  armswing_ros/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

There are a few possible solutions suggested that I've tried, and I haven't been able to get things to work correctly yet. I added `Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QTGui` to the `find_package()` call, `usr/include/qt4` to the `include_directories()` call,  `INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE}) ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})`, and a link to my package "armswing_ros" in the `target_link_libraries()` as such: `armswing_ros ${QT_LIBRARIES}`.

What do I need to do to get the Qt libraries available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212706/using-qt-libraries-with-ros-indigo-cmake-error/) by [jacob.t.hopkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/22913/jacob.t.hopkins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-04**:
Have you had any luck?

**Comment by [jacob.t.hopkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/22913/jacob.t.hopkins/) on 2015-07-06**:
Not so far. I was gone the end of last week so I've just started looking again. I'm not getting errors that libraries can't be found anymore, but I still don't have access to the necessary Qt components: QString, QFile, and QTextStream

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-06**:
Could you update your question with the Ubuntu version and the output of `qmake --version`?

**Comment by [jacob.t.hopkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/22913/jacob.t.hopkins/) on 2015-07-06**:
I managed to get it to work. The GUI was written using Qt4 libraries, which I couldn't import, but I could import Qt5 libraries, so I did. Then there was a bit of adding Qt4 directories back in where names had been changed and now it builds successfully. Thanks a bunch!

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-06**:
Absolutely! So this question may be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an example. This is a very simple Qt5 `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE)
project(ros_threading_example)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp
                            message_generation
                                      nav_msgs)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

add_message_files(FILES Pose2D.msg)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp message_generation
  DEPENDS system-lib
)
    
qt5_wrap_cpp(QT_MOC_HPP src/RobotThread.h)

include_directories(src ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(pose_echo_threaded src/main.cpp 
                                  src/RobotThread.cpp
                                  ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP}
                                  ${QT_MOC_HPP})

add_executable(pose_echo src/PoseEcho.cc)

add_dependencies(pose_echo ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)
add_dependencies(pose_echo_threaded ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)

target_link_libraries(pose_echo_threaded ${catkin_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(pose_echo ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS pose_echo_threaded pose_echo
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1